# JavaTimeModule serialization force LocalDateTime to convert to Long/timestamp?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, java-time

I have this code:

```
MyItem item = new MyItem();
item.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
Map<String, Object> fieldsToSetOnInsert = objectMapper.convertValue(item, Map.class);
```

Problem is this converts the "createdAt" field into an array, but I need it to be a timestamp (i.e. long) format. Is there a way to force this?

I tried using this, but did not work:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
```

Preferably something without annotating the class which is in another package. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is "long" format?
Does something like `{createdAt=2023-03-27T22:19:31.920571}` works for you?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use for tracking “when created”. That class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. You should be using `Instant` class, `Instant.now()`.

Comment: We use UTC everywhere, its not a problem.

Comment: When you use UTC, the correct classes to use are `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` with an offset of zero. The exact choice depends, so I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Preferably something without annotating the class which is in another package.

You can use mix-ins for that. For instance:

```
public interface MyItemMinIn {
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
    LocalDateTime getCreatedAt();
}
```

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(MyItem.class, MyItemMixIn.class);
```

The `ObjectMapper` will now merge the mix-in interface with your own class for its mapping configuration.

Answer (score -1):

The question is what really goes into setCreatedAt......    Noticed also, some things use toEpochMilli()

```
long andthen = (LocalDateTime.now()).toInstant().getEpochSecond();
item.setCreatedAt(andthen);
```

Comment: This would require changing the `MyItem` class. If no annotations can be added, making even more invasive changes like this will also not possible.

Comment: This cannot work. I get *'toInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset)' in 'java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime' cannot be applied to '()'*.

Comment: The code up there does not have that on the toInstant() either, why did you put that there! , Are you trying to tag on a timezone or are you trying to change the timezone, either way, they are the same moment as an epoch moment, that number would be the same. If the time must have at least a timezone tag then it must be in a ZonedDateTime or an OffsetDateTime. You would need to put in a property to hold the zone to have it stored as epoch second.